# In a dynamic_rnn do I need to bucket samples in order to balance batches?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am implementing a bidirectional dynamic rnn. Now I face the question whether I need to bucket my training samples.

My thought (and fear) is that if I don't bucket I might face the following situation: In a batch with 32 samples and maybe all but one samples being below 500 characters long and one samples being say 10.000 characters long the backprop will behave basically as if I had only a batch size of 1 and might result in NANs quickly or throw off the learned weights pretty badly every time that situation occurs.

Any experiences before I write code and check for days of training and debugging? Thx

Comment: Do you really have sample lengths that vary by two orders of magnitude?

Comment: Yes, I am training a char level rnn on email and web page data. Some emails are just a couple of words long, some web pages are really really long. Both these extremes are not the most relevant samples but I'd still like the system to be able to handle them without bucketing wrappers or cut off limits. "would like to" - if possible

Comment: If the distribution is really skewed such that there is only a really small percentage of data that is really long then you can sometimes get away with truncated those examples during training.